# Write a function to determine whether an array contains consecutive numbers for at least N numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to write a function to determine whether an array contains consecutive numbers for at least N numbers. For example, the input is `[1,5,3,4]` and `3`, it turns `true` because the array has `3` consecutive numbers, which is `[3,4,5]`

Here this function requires sorting beforehand and it is not the most eloquent solution in my opinion. Can someone take a look and make some improvements on this?

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N === 0) return true;
  const sortedArray = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let count = 0;
  let prev = null;
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (prev && num === prev + 1) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }
    if (count === N) return true;
    prev = num;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 4)) // false
```

Comment: I think sorting beforehand *is* the right way to go, if you want to minimize computational complexity. There might be another method, but your general strategy is the one I'd use too

Comment: Yes I agree with CertainPerformance. Or at least I can't think of a better / faster solution than sorting the array. Your code looks pretty efficient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the array first is not bad, but your program is broken by duplicates and returns false for `([4, 5, 5, 6], 3)`.  That's easily fixed.

Sorting first takes O(N log N) time.  You can do this in expected O(N) time, but the method is more complex and would probably only be faster for very large inputs.

It works like this:

1. Create a disjoint set data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure
2. Iterate through the array, mapping each unique integer you find to a set in that structure.
3. When you add a new integer, if sets exist for the preceding and following integers, then merge them with the new one.
4. When you're done, find the size of the largest set, which represents the largest sequence of consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could make some changes

- initialize `prev` with `undefined` (`null` acts as number zero if you add a number), this allowes to
- omit check with `prev`
- move check for count inside of the first `if`statement and exit early if the wanted incremented count is found.

```js
function hasConsecutiveNums(array, N) {
  if (array.length < N) return false;
  if (N === 0) return true;
  const sortedArray = array.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let count = 0;
  let prev = undefined;
  for (const num of sortedArray) {
    if (num === prev + 1) {
      if (++count === N) return true;
    } else {
      count = 1;
    }        
    prev = num;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 3)) // true
console.log(hasConsecutiveNums([1, 4, 5, 6], 4)) // false
```